# How to split a column in Python into multiple columns using different delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, split, latitude-longitude

I want so split a column in a dataframe into multiple columns.

This is the dataframe (df) I have:

```
object_id    shape            geometry
   1         450    polygon((6.6 51.2, 6.69 51.23, 6.69 51.2))
```

The output I want looks like this:

```
x      y    x    y      x    y
6.6  51.2  6.69  51.23  6.69  51.2
```

I am using this code:

```
df.geometry.str.split('( , )',expand=True)
```

but I'm getting an error.

Comment: I guess `polygon` should be an object, how you get the dataframe?

Comment: it is from a shapefile, i got it from a geodataframe and converted it into a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bit hacky, but we can do some string manipulation to re-create your dataframe.

```
s = df['geometry'].str.replace('polygon\(\(||\)\)','')\
      .str.split(',',expand=True).stack()\
      .str.strip().str.split(' ').explode().to_frame('vals')


s['cords'] =  s.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount().map({0 : 'x', 1 : 'y'})


df.join(s.set_index('cords',append=True).unstack([1,2]).droplevel(level=[0,1],axis=1))
```

---

```
   object  shape                                    geometry    x     y     x      y     x     y
0       1      2  polygon((6.6 51.2, 6.69 51.23, 6.69 51.2))  6.6  51.2  6.69  51.23  6.69  51.2
```

Comment: getting an error in first line `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: @GauravRaina so you have `NaN` values in your dataframe which are not strings. you can use `.fillna('')` first or `.dropna()`

Comment: No. there weren't any null values. However, geometry coloumn was not string and i converted into string now iam not getting an error. thanks.